# Accessing usb flash in qemu virtual machine while runnig windows 8

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, qemu, archlinux

I run this command in **arch linux** :

> qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -usbdevice host:4146:3257 -vga std -m 4048 -smp 4 -hda /mnt/win81.img

and this is my `lsusb` output :

> Bus 004 Device 003: ID 4146:3257 USBest Technology

I also create a rule in my 
**/etc/udev/rules.d/flash.rules**  for permissions .

> SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="4146", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3257", GROUP="users", MODE="0666"

but this error still remains :

```
libusb: error [_get_usbfs_fd] libusb couldn't open USB device /dev/bus/usb/004/003: Permission denied
libusb: error [_get_usbfs_fd] libusb requires write access to USB device nodes.
libusb: error [_get_usbfs_fd] libusb couldn't open USB device /dev/bus/usb/004/003: Permission denied
libusb: error [_get_usbfs_fd] libusb requires write access to USB device nodes.
libusb: error [_get_usbfs_fd] libusb couldn't open USB device /dev/bus/usb/004/003: Permission denied
libusb: error [_get_usbfs_fd] libusb requires write access to USB device nodes.
```

Comment: not sure if you have read this => https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udev but looking at your udev rule it appears your missing the, KERNEL=="" option / parameter / argument in the beginning of your rule.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try running it with root permission? I had same issue and doing a `sudo` worked well for me.